# Play multiple m3u8 files continuously in web HLS player

Tags: jwplayer, m3u8

On my server there is a directory on which m3u8 files are build continuously under a live streaming set up.
Now I want to stream those files in a web player that runs m3u8 in such a way that after a certain interval, player's SRC get updated with a new one (next m3u8 file in order) without any lag.

I could achive this using mediaelement.js but I have milliseconds flicker when switching to a new m3u8 file.

Can we play the files in such an order using Jw Player ? 
Its hls streaming is supported only for premium users thats why I want to know if its worth the price ?

Please help guys ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no way to seamlessly stitch multiple M3U8 manifests together within a player configuration. It would be possible to utilize a playlist to achieve this, but there would be gaps between loading new manifests.

If you're planning on using HLS for live streaming, you could continuously load new segments into the initial M3U8 manifest. This would maintain seamless video playback while still only using a single manifest.

Here's a demo of JW Player's livestreaming capabilities using a single M3U8 manifest: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/demos/toolbox/live-streaming/